# Execution failed for task ':processReleaseGoogleServices'

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin, ionic3

I'm having a problem upon getting my unsigned apk using the cli command,

***ionic cordova build --release android***

The error was this.

[image]

here is what my build.gradle looks like

[image]

I already tried to changethos '+' signs but it still didn't work.

Comment: tryed to set it as 9.0.0 instead? or 11.0.2?

Comment: yes, already tried to set it.